# Molecular biology - Lewin's Gene Xi vs Molecular Biology of the Cell by bruce albert

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, cell-biology, book-recommendation

I am an undergraduate and want to start reading about molecular biology. to anyone who has read both books please let me know your thoughts. which one should I go with?

**Lewin's Gene Xi** or **Molecular Biology of the Cell by Bruce Albert**

Answer (score 3):

They are both good books and standard texts, but they are not equivalent. Albert's "Molecular Biology of the Cell" is an overview of many aspects of cell biology: metabolism, genetics, cellular structure, intracellular communication, cancer, etc. Lewin's "Gene" really only covers genetics. It's a subset of the material in "Molecular Biology of the Cell", but it goes into more depth on many of the topics that it does cover.

Which book you should choose will depend on whether you are interested exclusively  in genetics, or if you want to cover other aspects of cellular biology too.